# Create log files with Serilog only if their is any logs

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog, ilogger, serilog-sinks-file

I want to write different logs on different log files with Serilog by API request.
The problem is when the log file configured within `LoggerConfiguration()`, they created no matter if their is any logs or not.
The problem is that I have many empty log files per request.
Maybe Serilog has the ability not to create file if it has no logs to write to that file? or maybe any other solution for this problem?

Comment: I _think_ The Serilog.Sinks.Map sink creates logs just in time?